# Is there a standard way to get previous login date of SAP user?

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I've got a requirement to check whether some objects were modified since last logon of current user. There is a table `USR02` that contains last logon date, but it is updated at moment of logon and here "last" means "current".

For example, I logged in 2014.11.21 and then 2014.11.26, so dates range I want to get is `21…26`, but when I enter the system, date 2014.11.21 in `USR02` will be overwritten with 2014.11.26.

Of course, I could follow Z-way and create my own table containing user name and previous login date, but maybe there is there a standard way to achieve this?

Comment: Look at function `SUSR_LOGON_USER_EXIT`. There is a `CALL CUSTOMER-FUNCTION '001'`, maybe this customer exit will let you read the last logon date during the login. Of course you would have to store it somewhere else anyway before it gets overwritten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that you can see the current as well as the last logon date and time in the dialog you can open with System --> Status. I went through the code of the function pool `SHSY` that contains this dialog and found the following implementation:

```
  DATA: BEGIN OF last_logon,
          date LIKE sy-datum,
          time LIKE sy-uzeit,
          date_now LIKE sy-datum,
          time_now LIKE sy-uzeit,
        END OF last_logon.

* ...

* Datum und Zeit der aktuellen und letzten Anmeldung
  GET PARAMETER ID 'US2' FIELD last_logon.
```

Certainly not the standard API one would expect, but apparently it's all there is...

Comment: Thank you very much. As I need to perform this check for current user, it works perfectly.

For quick reference: include `LSHSYO01` line 134 or FUGR `SHSY`, field `LAST_LOGON`.